# What are definitions as applied to C++ and CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have seen some reference to CMake's [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/target_compile_definitions.html). After reading it and some other references it is not clear to me. What exactly are definitions as applied to C++ compilation using CMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for setting preprocessor macros that are passed to the compilers preprocessor on the command-line.

For example

```
target_compile_definitions(some_target PRIVATE FOO=123)
```

will on GCC cause the option `-DFOO=123` to be passed, which defines the macro `FOO` with the body `123` (i.e. all instances of `FOO` in the source is replaced by `123`).

Comment: Asked this following a comment from my other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737859/generating-visual-studio-2017-projects-with-cmake). It is not clear to me what the comment meant as applied to my posted code.