# Compile mongo-c-driver

Tags: c, mongodb, mongo-c-driver

I'am trying to compile mongo-c-driver from [this link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases?after=1.2.0-beta1) regarding to described in [this link](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html).
I have compiled libbson successfulty, when i try to below command I get `The source directory "/" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" \ "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver" \ "-DBSON_ROOT_DIR=C:\mongo-c-driver"
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more descriptive about what you have actually done. You get errors typically because you have not really followed the instructions given.

Comment: @NeilLunn I downloaded "Source code (tar.gz)" file from [this address](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases). Regarding to Builnding in windows section in [this link](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html#building-on-windows) and started to run commands, libbson compiled and installed successfully. Then run `cd c:\mongo-c-driver-1.6.3` command and then I got error when running this command: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" \ "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver" \ "-DBSON_ROOT_DIR=C:\mongo-c-driver"`

Answer (score 2):

Use vcpkg.
follow instruction as mentioned on git 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg

step 1

C:\vcpkg>.\vcpkg search mongodb

Step 2

C:\vcpkg>.\vcpkg install mongo-c-driver

step 3

vcpkg integrate install

then simply use visual studio to include. vcpkg is smart it will do all background jobs for you.

you might be interested in it.
[How can I build a program using c++ driver of mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774805/how-can-i-build-a-program-using-c-driver-of-mongodb/46981525#46981525)