# Problems building mongo-c-driver-1.16.2 for Win64

Tags: c, mongodb, dll, cmake, mongo-c-driver

I need to compile the MongoDB driver for windows x64 (.dll extension). I was following [this tutorial](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html) with visual studio 16 2019 and cmake 3.17.0, but I found several problems:

1. First step is:

```
$ cd mongo-c-driver-x.y.z
$ mkdir cmake-build
$ cd cmake-build
$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" \
    "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver" \
    "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\mongo-c-driver" \
    ..
```

But I received errors about missing information at top of the CMakeLists.txt file. cmake_minimum_required & project(). So I wrote them.

2. Then, at the end of the file it was written the following:

```
set_dist_list (src_libmongoc_tests_DIST
   CMakeLists.txt
   ${src_libmongoc_tests_DIST_cs}
   ${src_libmongoc_tests_DIST_hs}
   ${src_libmongoc_tests_DIST_zeros}
   ${src_libmongoc_tests_DIST_pems}
   ${src_libmongoc_tests_DIST_dats}
   ${src_libmongoc_tests_DIST_txts}
   ${src_libmongoc_tests_DIST_jsons}
)
```

I had to erase it because of error with the set_dist_list command

3. Once erased it worked well with the command:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A "x64" -S "C:\...\mongo-c-driver-1.16.2" -B "C:\...\mongo-c-driver-1.16.2\cmake-build3" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver" "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\mongo-c-driver"
```

4. Next step was:

```
$ msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

It worked well.

5. Next step was:

```
$ msbuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj
```

There wasn't INSTALL.vcxproj file, so I couldn't execute the command. I tried several times but didn't find solution to the problem. But I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101791/compile-mongo-c-driver) on stackoverflow. I followed all the steps but when I searched for mongo-c-driver there was only the 1.15.1 available. I continued anyways but when the process finished I found that the drivers where **x86** and not x64 (they're in a folder called x86-windows) and the drivers seem to be **1.0 version** (they are called libmongoc-1.0.dll &  libbson-1.0.dll).

So, the conclusion is that I wasted a lot of time I couldn't build the drivers. What I did wrong on both processes? How I can get the last version of the mongo-c-driver compiled for x64 on .dll format?

Many thanks for your time and responses, I don't know how to continue,

Héctor

Comment: If a project supports CMake then "Missing information cmake_minimum_required & project" almost always means you are running CMake from the wrong directory. Find the most toplevel directory where the `CMakeLists.txt` file contains those information and rerun your commands from there.

Comment: I was at the top level directory (mongo-c-driver-1.16.2). I checked it again.

Comment: Okay, I have found that I can get the x64 version on vcpkg with the "--triplet x64-windows" options. But I still get the 1.0 version. I also continue without knowing why the first way isn't working.

Comment: As a general note: the version isn't typically present in a *.dll* name. If it was, imagine *software-x.y.dll* When a new minor version was released it would be *software-x.y+1.dll*, meaning that all software that uses that *.dll* would have to be recompiled, which makes no sense. I didn't work with *Mongo*, but *1.0* seems fine. Right click on the file *Properties->Details* (maybe the version is stored there).

Comment: OK. Just downloaded the last version 1.16.2 and followed the instructions. My command line call for a cmd command prompt was `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF ..` from the build dir. I could run CMake on this project without any hassle. Do you run this command from a cmd or a powershell or something other?

Comment: @CristiFati Yes, that makes sense. Maybe now I have the 1.15.1 version that is from one year ago, but that it's much better than having nothing.

Comment: @Héctor: You didn't get my point. What I was trying to say that the *1.0* at the end at the *.dll* name is not necessarily the version. Could be *1.16.2*, or *1.15*, or *1.\**. Try alternate ways for finding the version (I gave one in the previous comment, or look at the build logs). But I totally don't get how building a certain version of sources would yield a different version of the artifact.

Comment: @vre from cmd. If I copypaste your command or run mine posted above I get the following error: Unknown CMake command "set_dist_list".

Comment: @CristiFati No, I got it. Sorry if I didn't explained well myself. The 1.15.1 was the only version available through vcpckg, that's why I suposed that my version is this one and not 1.0 or 1.16.2 or whatever. The version isn't store on the file properties, I will try to search in the logs. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I am using CMake 3.14.3. Maybe that makes the difference.As CMake 3.17.0 is bleedign edge can you try an older version?

Comment: @vre I have deleted my CMake version and ins taled yours (3.14.3). If I write my command or yours I get the same error output: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (set_dist_list):
  Unknown CMake command "set_dist_list".

Comment: @vre Maybe may you upload your 1.16.2 x64 dll?

Comment: What source file did you downloaded from projects GitHub releases? The `Source code (zip)` did not work on my computer. Instead I downloaded the *.tar.gz form this link: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/download/1.16.2/mongo-c-driver-1.16.2.tar.gz

Comment: Wow, now it just works... I downloaded the .zip version. With the .tar.gz works perfectly line by line. Thank you so much. How can I mark you as solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial for building mongo-c-driver on Windows is missing the step which source should be downloaded (as the paragraphs for other platforms provide). So one might be tempted to download `Source code (zip)` from the releases page. This will only get you a copy of the repository when the tag was set. But it is essential to use the `mongo-c-driver-1.16.2.tar.gz` link on the releases page. Then everything should work.