# Build a c++ project with mongodb

Tags: c++, database, mongodb, database-connection, mongo-cxx-driver

I want to save measurements in a mongoDB document and use this data in further operations.

I have followed the steps described in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46981525/10584541) by Joyo Waseem to install the needed driver. 
However, I still get several Error Messages (82 to be specific) in some of the files (alignment_of.hpp; is_nothrow_move_assignable.hpp; view_or_value.hpp; types.hpp; etc). These are just some files which create an error.

The error-messages are:

> `Severity Code    Line    Description
>   Error (active)  E0243   36  class or struct definition is missing
>   Error (active)  E1574   29  static assertion failed with "Arguments to is_nothrow_move_constructible must be complete types"
>   Error (active)  E0070   31  incomplete type is not allowed
>   Error (active)  E1574   31  static assertion failed with "Arguments to is_nothrow_move_assignable must be complete types"
>   Error (active)  E0262   36  not a class or struct name
>   Error (active)  E1018   36  namespace "bsoncxx" has no member class "view_or_value"
>   Error (active)  E0070   41  incomplete type is not allowed
>   Error (active)  E0276   41  name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
>   Error (active)  E0260   48  explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
>   Error (active)  E0135   48  namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   48  expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0276   56  name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
>   Error (active)  E0260   63  explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
>   Error (active)  E0135   63  namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   63  expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0070   64  incomplete type is not allowed
>   Error (active)  E0276   72  name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
>   Error (active)  E0260   79  explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
>   Error (active)  E0135   79  namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   79  expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0145   86  member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_double::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0276   87  name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
>   Error (active)  E0260   94  explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
>   Error (active)  E0135   94  namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   94  expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0276   102 name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
>   Error (active)  E0106   105 invalid type for a bit field
>   Error (active)  E0040   105 expected an identifier
>   Error (active)  E0260   109 explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
>   Error (active)  E0135   109 namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   109 expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0145   111 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_utf8::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0106   114 invalid type for a bit field
>   Error (active)  E0040   114 expected an identifier
>   Error (active)  E0260   124 explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
>   Error (active)  E0135   124 namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   124 expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0077   127 this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
>   Error (active)  E0135   127 namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   127 expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0077   128 this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
>   Error (active)  E0135   128 namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   128 expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0077   129 this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
>   Error (active)  E0135   129 namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   129 expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0077   130 this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
>   Error (active)  E0135   130 namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   130 expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0077   131 this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
>   Error (active)  E0135   131 namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   131 expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0077   132 this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
>   Error (active)  E0135   132 namespace "mongocxx::v_noabi::stdx" has no member "optional"
>   Error (active)  E0065   132 expected a ';'
>   Error (active)  E0145   149 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_document::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   181 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_array::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0106   181 invalid type for a bit field
>   Error (active)  E0018   181 expected a ')'
>   Error (active)  E0106   190 invalid type for a bit field
>   Error (active)  E0040   190 expected an identifier
>   Error (active)  E0145   206 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_binary::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   230 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_undefined::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   246 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_oid::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0106   262 invalid type for a bit field
>   Error (active)  E0018   262 expected a ')'
>   Error (active)  E0145   264 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_bool::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0106   271 invalid type for a bit field
>   Error (active)  E0040   271 expected an identifier
>   Error (active)  E0145   289 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_date::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   350 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_null::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   366 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_regex::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   402 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_dbpointer::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   421 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_code::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   462 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_symbol::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   500 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_codewscope::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   533 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_int32::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   562 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_timestamp::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   581 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_int64::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   606 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_decimal128::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   637 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_minkey::type_id" may not be initialized
>   Error (active)  E0145   653 member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_maxkey::type_id" may not be initialized`

I don‘t know if I have done something wrong/skipt something that is considered as an unspoken standard or if some parts of the software are incompatible. 
Just to make sure, if I have used vcpkg to install the drivers, do I still need to include some directories in the properties? Like for example the additional-Include Directory? Is there also a difference between using vcpkg and cmake?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit unclear from your question what your code is doing. I will include an example on how to build the sample code below.
vcpkg is a packaging manager and cmake is a build tool.

Setup vcpkg in a command prompt:

```
cd vcpkg
bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
vcpkg install mongo-cxx-driver
```

Setup a Visual Studio project
[image]
Add source code
[image]
[image]

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>

using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;

int main() {
    mongocxx::client mongo_client{ mongocxx::uri{"mongodb://localhost:27017"} };
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Build Solution

```
1>------ Build started: Project: mongodb, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>mongodb.vcxproj -> D:\dev\cpptest\mongodb\Debug\mongodb.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The to run the .exe you need to add D:\dev\GitHub\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\bin to the path. This is so that the .exe can find the mongocxx.dll

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Your describtion helped me alot now I have no error-messages anymore. 
However, if I want to debug it, it autmatically stops because of an unhandled exeption.
in the output section it says:
`Exception thrown at 0x0FB8AC5C (libmongoc-1.0.dll) in mongodb_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000038.
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
**Addend** was 0x38.`

Comment: I've done some research and found a side which recomments to delet the files which are stored in the data/db folder. After doing this I opend my project again and no it indicates that I have 70 errors again. I've looked up some of the messages but couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: Please select my answer as correct. If you have issues with debugging raise a new question and we will look into it as well.