# I get an error running the base C++ code for MongoDB with WIndows 10, Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, mongodb, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I have a problem with running the basic C++ code for MongoDB. Works on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019. I was able to add libraries for mongocxx etc thanks to vcpkg.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
int main(int, char**) {
    mongocxx::instance instance{}; // This should be done only once.
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    mongocxx::client conn(uri);
    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};
    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";
    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});
    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When running this code with `mongocxx :: uri uri ("mongodb: // localhost: 27017");` everything works
but when it runs with `mongocxx :: uri uri ("mongodb + srv: // <username>: <password> @ <cluster-url> / test? retryWrites = true & w = majority" ");` (I use the one that works in MongoDBCompass) Error appears.

```
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\moje pliki\VS 2019\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\moje pliki\VS 2019\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\bsoncxx.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\moje pliki\VS 2019\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\mongocxx.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\moje pliki\VS 2019\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\bson-1.0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\moje pliki\VS 2019\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\mongoc-1.0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\moje pliki\VS 2019\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\zlibd1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. 
The thread 0x44e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\NapiNSP.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pnrpnsp.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winrnr.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nlaapi.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wshbth.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\schannel.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mskeyprotect.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ncrypt.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntasn1.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scksp.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\credui.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinSCard.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x003CE0A0.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ncryptprov.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winsta.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 (KernelBase.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0x8010002E: Could not find smart card reader.
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 (KernelBase.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0x0000071A: The remote procedure call was canceled, or if a call time-out was specified, the call timed out.
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x003CDB7C.
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wincredui.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x0123F734.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rlls.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Win32Util::Error at memory location 0x02DDF7A0.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\umpdc.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.CredDialogController.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Win32Util::Error at memory location 0x02DDF5C0.
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Win32Util::Error at memory location 0x02DDF5C0.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.XamlHost.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.Cred.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wincorlib.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MrmCoreR.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\InputHost.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\LanguageOverlayUtil.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BCP47mrm.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dcomp.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BCP47Langs.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BCP47Langs.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BCP47Langs.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.Immersive.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\twinapi.appcore.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rmclient.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DXCore.dll'. 
onecore\base\appmodel\statemanager\apiset\lib\statespace.cpp(107)\kernelbase.dll!772298F6: (caller: 77229899) ReturnHr(1) tid(2e58) 80073D54 The process has no package identity
onecore\base\appmodel\statemanager\apiset\lib\statemanager.cpp(53)\kernelbase.dll!77284CA6: (caller: 784630EA) ReturnHr(2) tid(2e58) 80073D54 The process has no package identity.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Globalization.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Globalization.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Globalization.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_c87780efe1918cc5\nvldumd.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptnet.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imagehlp.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_c87780efe1918cc5\nvwgf2um.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_c87780efe1918cc5\nvwgf2um.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_c87780efe1918cc5\nvwgf2um.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
The thread 0x230c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_c87780efe1918cc5\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_c87780efe1918cc5\NvCamera\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d2d1.dll'. 
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d2d1.dll'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d2d1.dll'. 
The thread 0x1e68 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 (KernelBase.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0x40080202: WinRT transform error (parameters: 0x8000000B, 0x80070490, 0x0000001E, 0x0321CA20).
Exception thrown at 0x772546D2 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x0321D290.

The program '[10268] ConsoleApplication2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Am I skipping a step before running?
I noticed that the code stops running at:
`collection.insert_one(document.view());`

---

EDIT:
I started the settings for MongoDB, C ++, Windows with this instructions:
http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html and http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/windows/
however, I did not fully understand it, and I was not able to complete it.
then I found information about vcpkg here: in a post from @Joyo Waseem [How to set up project with mongodb-cxx-driver in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040998/how-to-set-up-project-with-mongodb-cxx-driver-in-visual-studio)
and it all worked for local DBs.But unfortunately, for the connection to the server, there are a few errors, here are some of them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jYq7.png

I'm not sure if I should apply any more settings for Linker and others.
I have tried these settings yet:[Build a c++ project with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685960/build-a-c-project-with-mongodb)
but I think they are unnecessary due to the use of: `C:\vcpkg>.\Vcpkg integrate install`
Tried running VS 2019 as administrator.
I held my anti-virus action.
I also reached for the oldest form of repair - restarting the computer.

---

EDIT2 :
I installed Visual Studio 2015. Then I set Tools> Options> Debugging> Symbols -> checked the Microsoft Symbol Server option. (I don't know why I found such information somewhere). Now, when trying to run the code, the only message I receive is the window security - smart card.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeS9O.png
I don't have one and I don't know where this message is coming from. Does it result from the settings of the Windows 10 system or from the settings in MongoDB.

---

EDIT3 :
I dusted off my old Windows 7 PC. Installed Visual Studio 2019, setup vcpkg for mongo-cxx-drivers and code run in the first try. Can I somehow use this build and run it worked on the new computer?

```
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\cosbedzie\Debug\cosbedzie.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Antivirus\x86\aswhook.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\cosbedzie\Debug\bsoncxx.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\cosbedzie\Debug\bson-1.0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\cosbedzie\Debug\mongocxx.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\cosbedzie\Debug\mongoc-1.0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Marcin\source\repos\cosbedzie\Debug\zlibd1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
The thread 0x1fcc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nlaapi.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\NapiNSP.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pnrpnsp.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wshbth.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winrnr.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WSHTCPIP.DLL'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wship6.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\credssp.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\schannel.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ncrypt.dll'. 
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wship6.dll'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WSHTCPIP.DLL'
The thread 0x524 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nlaapi.dll'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\NapiNSP.dll'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pnrpnsp.dll'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wshbth.dll'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winrnr.dll'
'cosbedzie.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL'
The thread 0x240 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1d78 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x141c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7872] cosbedzie.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

---

EDIT4 :
I took all the settings from the old computer now it is left with an error
`Unhandled exception at 0x761446D2 in nowycalkiem.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: mongocxx::v_noabi::bulk_write_exception at memory location 0x00AFE6AC.`
and
`Unhandled exception at 0x761446D2 in nowycalkiem.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: mongocxx::v_noabi::query_exception at memory location 0x00AFEBB8.`

---

EDIT5 :
I set up the latest drivers for C ++ (mongo-c-driver-1.17.3, mongo-cxx-driver-r3.6.2) because drivers from vcpkg  have: C - 1.16.1 # 3, C ++ - 3.4.0-5 # 1
After following these steps:
http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html
http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/windows/
[How to set up Visual Studio project settings with mongo-cxx-driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828845/how-to-set-up-visual-studio-project-settings-with-mongo-cxx-driver)
I wrote the code according to this instruction:
http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/helpers.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/array.hpp>


using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;

int main(int, char**) {
 mongocxx::instance inst{};
 mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{"mongodb+srv://new:new123@wipcluster.qetq2.mongodb.net/userdata?retryWrites=true&w=majority"} };
 mongocxx::database db = conn["userdata"];
 mongocxx::collection coll = db["test"];
 auto builder = bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{};
 bsoncxx::document::value doc_value = builder
     << "name" << "MongoDB"
     << "type" << "database"
     << "count" << 1
     << "versions" << bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array
     << "v3.2" << "v3.0" << "v2.6"
     << close_array
     << "info" << bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document
     << "x" << 203
     << "y" << 102
     << bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document
     << bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;

 bsoncxx::document::view view = doc_value.view();

 bsoncxx::stdx::optional<mongocxx::result::insert_one> result =
     coll.insert_one(view);

}
```

And the expectation reappeared:
`Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC99A73B29 in Project3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: mongocxx::v_noabi::bulk_write_exception at memory location 0x0000001D6D6FE0C0.`

Comment: I suspect I mixed up compiling with running.  I have no Errors and "No Issues found" sign.  I have only those Exception thrown.

Comment: Is this URI string `"mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-url>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"` the actual string you are using or did you substitute the `<username>`, `<password>`, `<cluster-url>`, and `test` with your real user name, password, cluster URL and database name?

Comment: Do you have different authentication and target databases? Does this thread help?: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/185783

Comment: @heap underrun yes i use this ```mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb+srv://new:new123@wipcluster.qetq2.mongodb.net/userdata?retryWrites=true&w=majority");``` - it is workin in MongoDB Compass
and use the uri that MongoDB Atlas generates for me: ```mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@wipcluster.qetq2.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: The final exception appears to be raised from a XAML UI. Further up there's apparently an attempt to launch the system's credentials dialog. This appears to be in response of a (failed?) attempt to look up the credentials in a system credential store.

Comment: @IInspectable one thing makes me wonder. since Debug is from x86 and Win32 is selected, why are dll files loaded from SysWOW64?

Comment: You are running 32-bit code on a 64-bit OS. The technology that enables this is called "Windows on Windows", or WoW for short. In this case referencing binaries from the SysWOW64 folder is to be expected. The 64-bit binaries are located in the System32 folder.

Comment: The screenshot does not exhibit a runtime error (nor a compile time error). It's just telling you that the debugger cannot find debug information to enable it to show symbols. You will need to tell your debugger where to find debug information (in a local PDB file, from a symbol server, or, rarely, embedded in the binary).

Comment: @IInspectable - I installed Visual Studio 2015 and the only message I receive is the window security - smart card.I don't have one and I don't know where this message is coming from.